# read from Ultrasonic HC-SR04

Tags: c, pic, microc

i want to run two HC-SR04 on one PIC16F877A and send the value mesured by the two ultrasonic to serial port.

this is my code using PIC C Compiler :

```html
#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=PIN_C6,rcv=PIN_C7,bits=8) 
#define e1 PIN_B6
#define t1 pin_B7 
#define e2 pin_B4 
#define t2 pin_B5 
int a; 
int distanse(int,int); 

void main()
{

while(1){
int u1,u2;
u1=distanse(e1,t1);u2=distanse(e2,t2);
printf("%3u", u1);
printf("%3u", u2);
delay_ms(1000);

}
}

int distanse(int e,int t){
long long counter=0;
output_bit(t,1);delay_us(10);output_bit(t,0);
a=input(e);
while(a==0){a=input(e);}
while(a==1){counter=counter+1;a=input(e);}
return counter/3.333333;
}
```

but computer received random values ! what is the problem ?

Comment: RS-232 has three wires,  xmit, recv, and gnd.   I'm not seeing the provision for the ground line.

Comment: In my experience, incorrect characters points to a grounding error.

Comment: consistent indentation of the code blocks make the code ever so much easier for humans to read/understand.  Suggest indent 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'

Comment: after looking at the spec for the HC-SR04 device, it looks like RS232 is not a consideration.    How did you calculate the 3.333333 value?

Comment: the code is accumulating an integer value, then dividing it by a double value then converting it back to a integer value.   Plenty of opportunity for conversion errors.  have you run the code with a debugger?  what is the (typical) value of 'counter'?

Comment: does the circuit your using have a (as it should) common ground between the PIC and the HC-SR04 devices?

Comment: in your test setup, what is the range to the echo target?  is the echo target large enough to be distinctive?   It needs to be large enough (for testing) to completely cover the 15degree measuring angle, and unmoving, in the range 2cm to 2m.

Answer (score 0):

per the documentation for the device,

"You only need to
 supply a short 10uS 
pulse to the trigger input to start the ranging, an
d then the module will send out 
an 8 cycle burst of ultrasound at 40 kHz and raise 
its echo. The Echo is a 
distance object that is pulse width and the range i
n proportion .***You can 
calculate the range through the time interval betwe
en sending trigger signal and 
receiving echo signal.*** Formula: uS / 58 = centimete
rs or uS / 148 =inch; or: the 
range = high level time * velocity (340M/S) / 2; ***we
 suggest to use over 60ms 
measurement cycle, in order to prevent trigger sign
al to the echo signal***"

the measurement is NOT how long the signal stays high, but rather the time BETWEEN the end of the 'start' pulse and the beginning of the input signal being high.

Therefore, the code is measuring the wrong interval.

It should be measuring the 'low' interval, not the 'high' interval.

The documentation is available at:
http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf

Of note, since your running two of the devices, the time between measurements (of any device), per the documentation, needs to be over 60msec.

I'm not seeing the needed time interval between triggering the different devices.

I would suggest using the delay_us() function for time interval measurement rather than a free running while loop

Comment: or you can use interrupts that actually trigger on the reception of the ECHO signal from the HCSR04

Answer (score 0):

While Interfacing, ensure following steps

1. PIC microcontroller needs to transmit at least 10 us trigger pulse to the HC-SR04 Trig Pin.
2. After getting trigger pulse, HC-SR04 automatically sends eight 40 kHz sound wave and waits for rising edge output at Echo pin.
3. When the rising edge capture occurs at Echo pin which is connected to the input of PIC, start Timer of PIC18F4550 and again wait for falling edge on Echo pin.
4. As soon as the falling edge is captured at the Echo pin, microcontroller read the count of the Timer. This time count is used to calculate the distance to an object.

Looking to your program, Not sure that counter will work in this way. for better accuracy use Timer with Capture mode. find the more about it here: [PIC controller Timer Capture mode](http://electronicwings.com/pic/pic18f4550-timer-capture).

Using Timer to calculate the distance with Ultrasonic module, refer this 
    [Interfacing PIC controller with Ultrasonic sensor module HC-SR04](http://electronicwings.com/pic/ultrasonic-module-hc-sr04-interfacing-with-pic18f4550)